# type to be send as string

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm playing with below valid types.

```
type P = 'FACEBOOK' | 'GOOGLE' | 'JWT';

type Unio<U extends string> = {
    [K in U]: K
};

const PR: Unio<P> = {
    FACEBOOK: 'facebook',
    GOOGLE: 'google',
    JWT: 'jwt',
};

const providers: Map<(keyof typeof PR), IOAuthProvider> = new Map([
    [
        'FACEBOOK' as P, {
            clientID: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET,
        },
    ],
]);
```

What my expectation, is not to throw any type error if I remove `as P` as shown below. I want to remove it just to save extra typings.

```
const providers: Map<(keyof typeof PR), IOAuthProvider> = new Map([
    [
        'FACEBOOK', {
            clientID: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET,
        },
    ],
]);
```

But errors are thrown as below.

```
[ts]
Type 'Map<string, { clientID: string; clientSecret: string; }>' is not assignable to type 'Map<P, IOAuthProvider>'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'P'.
```

Comment: Using string enum could simplify the whole thing

Comment: can you comment using enum?

Answer (score 0):

To use your example, you could use your `PR`map, like this:

```
type P = 'FACEBOOK' | 'GOOGLE' | 'JWT';

type Unio<U extends string> = {
    [K in U]: K
};

const PR: Unio<P> = {
    FACEBOOK: 'FACEBOOK',
    GOOGLE: 'GOOGLE',
    JWT: 'JWT',
};

const providers: Map<(keyof typeof PR), any> = new Map([
    [
        PR.FACEBOOK, {clientID: '', clientSecret: '' },
    ],
]);
```

Notes: `'FACEBOOK' !== 'facebook'` - so I have used the same casing in both areas.

Comment: the reason I wouldn't like to add `PR.FACEBOOK` is to automatically populate providers from json file.

Comment: That should work. `PR.FACEBOOK` is just the string 'FACEBOOK' so it will serialize and deserialize as I think you want.

Answer (score 0):

This not answers your question, but because you asked for example with enum. I'm posting it here as it will not fit the comment space:

```
enum PR {
    FACEBOOK = 'FACEBOOK',
    GOOGLE = 'GOOGLE',
    JWT = 'JWT',
};

const providers: Map<PR, any> = new Map([
    [
        PR.FACEBOOK, { },
    ],
]);
```